# react-native start giving Invalid regular expression invalid error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-cli, metro-bundler

I followed following link to get started with react-native

[Getting started with react native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started)

I tried to create native app without expo
so i as per documentation i followed following command

```
npm install -g react-native-cli
react-native init AwesomeProject
```

After run android command

```
react-native run-android
```

It gave me following error on emulator

[image]

So i used start command to run metro server

```
react-native start
```

This command  gave me another error in console

[image]

Comment: I don't know if it works but try to turn off hermes and try it once.https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/hermes/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Its compatibility issue of Nodejs
I uninstalled my Node(12.11) and installed Node(10) stable version and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 69):

There is a problem with Metro using some NPM and Node versions.

You hay 2 alternatives:

- **Alternative 1:** Uninstall node and npm and reinstall with another (compatible) version:
  https://nodejs.org/en/download

---

- **Alternative 2:** Go to a file in your **npde_modules** folder:   `\node_modules\metro-config\src\defaults\blacklist.js` and change this code:

```js
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[/\\]react[/\\]dist[/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

to this:

```js
var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];
```

> Please note that if you run `npm install` or `yarn install` you'll need to change the code again.

Comment: The second alternative worked for me, the first for nothing (testing in 3 node previous versions 12 | 10 | 9)

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to change the `blacklist.js` file in module `metro-config` files as answered above. But each time you run `npm/yarn install` you will have to change it again.

So I came up with a solution that will save you time form going to the file and changing it each time:

I used a library that edit files using JavaScript:

1. Install Replace-in-file module:

```
npm install --save replace-in-file
```

2. Create a file at the same level as `node_module` folder name it: `metro-fix.js` per example.
3. Copy paste this script in it:

```
//Load the library
const replace = require('replace-in-file');
// path for metro config file
const path = 'node_modules/metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist.js';
// creating options for editing the file
const options = [
  {
    files: path,
    from: 'modules[/',
    to: 'modules[\\/',
  },
  {
    files: path,
    from: 'react[/',
    to: 'react[\\/',
  },
  {
    files: path,
    from: 'dist[/',
    to: 'dist[\\/',
  },
];

try {
  let results;
  // looping on each option
  options.forEach(e => {
    results = replace.sync(e);
    console.log('Replacing "'+e.from+'" by "'+e.to+'"  results:', results[0].hasChanged);
  });

} catch (error) {
  console.error('Error occurred:', error);
}
```

4. Now each time you run `npm install` just run:

```
node metro-fix.js
```

See [Replace-in-file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace-in-file) docs.

Answer (score 1):

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58120990/question-getting-error-on-react-native-start/58199866#58199866) may be this solution might work for you cause i applied and it worked

Answer (score 1):

When you install the NodeJS using the choco command(**choco install -y nodejs.install python2 jdk8**), it will install the latest version of node which is 12.12.0 at the time of writing this answer. You have to downgrade it to 10.16.3 and ***run the react-native run-android*** command and it should work fine

Answer (score 1):

yeah, just shift to Node version 10 and it will work.

```
nvm install <version>
nvm use <version>
```

it works...... :)

Comment: Hi Shekhar, welcome to Stack Overflow and thank you for contributing. Since you are new to SO, here are some tips on how to write better answers: (1) You are assuming that the user is not using node v10. You could comment asking for clarification. (2) You are also assuming that the person is using `nvm`. The person asking the question may not know what it is and it may add to their confusion.

Answer (score 0):

close Commands prompt and metro bundler,do it again

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with this step :

1. Uninstall node v12 and install node v8.9.4
2. re-install react-native-cli
3. re-create project `react-native init myApp --version 0.60.0`
4. `react-native start`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

yes i am also facing this issues. actually Node.js Recommended For Most Users is version 10.16.3 LTS.
Using below choco command will install Latest version of 12.11.0.
choco install -y nodejs.install python2 jdk8

I downgrade Node version from 12.11.0 to 10.16.3 LTS and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the node version is higher.

1. One of the solutions is that you can easily downgrade the node version from `12.x` to `10.x` or uninstall 12.x and install 10.x
2. On the other hand what if you want to use 12.x for some other project.
   So the below solution makes it easier. You can nvm which can control the multiple versions of node.

So first install nvm from here https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases

Once installed remember to add the nvm path to system variable

then `nvm install 10.18.1 64`

then `nvm install 12.14.1 64`

to list all the versions installed `nvm list`

whenever you want to switch from one version to another version use the command

```
nvm use 10.18.1  OR nvm use 12.14.1
```