# expo start showing unterminated character clause error

Tags: react-native, expo

So I'm currently trying to use expo start to test a project on my phone. However, when I do so I get the following error:

> Invalid regular expression: /(node_modules[\]react[\]dist[\].*|website\node_modules\.*|heapCapture\bundle.js|.*\__tests__\.*)$/: Unterminated character class

How can I fix this error?

```
node version: 13.6.0

npm version: 13.6

react version: 16.2.0

react-native version: 0.52.0

expo version: 6.3.1

windows: 7(can't currently upgrade)
```

All help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading to Node.js 12.8 will resolve this. Please see attached link

[react-native start giving Invalid regular expression invalid error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58117377/react-native-start-giving-invalid-regular-expression-invalid-error)

Comment: Thank you. How can I do this?

Comment: https://www.surrealcms.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-or-downgrade-nodejs-using-npm.html